# Spring MVC 3 validation with annotations - not showing form:errors

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I've been stuck with this about one hour, this is not the first time i am doing this but I cant figure it out.

It should show me the form errors, instead it throws this exception.

LE: i managed to solve the exception in the meantime, but i still cant see the errors. they are not rendered

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
>   Field error in object 'category' on field 'name': rejected value [jk]; codes [Range.category.name,Range.name,Range.java.lang.String,Range]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [category.name,name]; arguments []; default message [name],25,3]; default message [gfhghj]
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:894)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>       org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
>       org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
>       org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
>       org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>       org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
>       org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>       org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:101)
>       org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>       org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
>       org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>       org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
>       org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>       org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
>       org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>       org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
>       org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>       org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
>       org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>       org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
>       org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>       org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
>       org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>       org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
>       org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
>       org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
>       org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
>       org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
>       org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
>       org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/category")
public class CategoryController {

@Autowired
StockGateway stockGateway;

@RequestMapping(value = "add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addCategory(@Valid @ModelAttribute("category") CategoryAdd category, ModelMap model,
        BindingResult binding) {

    if (binding.hasErrors()) {
        return "category.add";
    }
    CategoryDTO dto = Converter.toCategory(category);
    try {
        stockGateway.createCategory(dto);
    } catch (StockGatewayException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "redirect:/category/add";

}

@RequestMapping(value = "add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String initView(ModelMap model) {
    model.put("category", new CategoryAdd());
    return "category.add";
}
```

}

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<div xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" 
xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags"
 xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" 
 xmlns:security = "http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"
 xmlns:util="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/util"
 xmlns:form="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"
 version="2.0">
```

```
<security:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_STOCK')" var="isStock">
    <form:form modelAttribute="category"  method="POST" action="add"  >
            <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name  :</td> <td> <form:input path="name" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td> <td> <form:errors path="name" cssClass="error" /></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <form:button>Add</form:button>
    </form:form>
</security:authorize>
```

```
public class CategoryAdd {

@Range(min= 3 , max = 25, message="gfhghj")
private String name;



public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

Comment: Are you absolutely certain `binding.hasErrors()` is returning true?

Comment: Yes. I am using Tiles. Could that have anything to do with it?

Comment: Yea, well if `binding.hasErrors()` is false you will be redirected to a GET instead of returning from a POST, any request data would be lost at that point.  Not to mention no errors actually being there :)

Comment: Have you tried to put the @Range on the getter?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There seems to be a dependency on the order in which the parameters must be listed in the mapped controller method.
For example:

```
public String addCategory(@Valid CategoryAdd category,BindingResult result, 
Map map)
```

Will work, whereas:

```
public String addCategory(@Valid CategoryAdd category, Map map, 
BindingResult result)
```

Will not.  I don't full understand why this is, especially as it compiles without any issues.

Comment: Thanks for this. i had exactly the same problem, and couldnt figure it out. After much searching I found this, and it did indeed turn out that I must have my `Model` after `BindingResult` in the params list

Comment: order seems to be an issue. i had the HttpServletRequest before the bindingResult which made it give the error

Comment: The Errors or BindingResult parameters have to follow the model object that is being bound
immediately as the method signature might have more that one model object and Spring will create a
separate BindingResult instance for each of them so the following sample won’t work:     http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-arguments

Comment: Just wanted to say this was helpful.  Lots of solutions but the order ended up being my actual problem.

Comment: Yes, thanks. But I was wondering why and conclude that probably in situations where have 2 forms for example and 2 BindingResults we can decide to which of them to put the error, so Spring choose the parameters just after the @Valid.

Answer (score 0):

So complete solution is:

```
public String addCategory(@Valid CategoryAdd category,BindingResult result,
        Map map
        ) {

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        map.put("categoryAdd", (CategoryAdd)result.getTarget());
        return "category.add";
    }
    CategoryDTO dto = Converter.toCategory(category);
    try {
        stockGateway.createCategory(dto);
    } catch (StockGatewayException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "redirect:/category/add";
```

Notice i changed parameter ModelMap with Map, and if the result has errors i put back the model from the result.

Now the WTF:
The BindingResult has a field objectName, which has the value the name of the class.
You have to set the modelAttribute/commandName to that. To be the same as objectName in BindingResult, or else it wont render the errors. 
So to match it:

```
    <form:form modelAttribute="categoryAdd" commandName="categoryAdd"  method="POST" action="add"  >
```

Does anyone know how can we change the objectName from the BindingResult? By default it will take the name of the class.

Comment: instead of `map.put("categoryAdd", (CategoryAdd)result.getTarget());` you could directly use the category parameter: `map.put("category", category);` -- btw, the model attribute name should be "category" not "category.add"

Comment: the model name is now  categoryAdd everywhere  so to satisfy form:errors. category.add is the view name

Comment: Is that something to do with the url mapping, when we have the request mapping we have like RequestMapping(value="/add", method = RequestMethodType.POST) but i am not seeing any "/" in your mapping. Does that make any difference? Just a guess.

Comment: @Blitzkr1eg Try creating  a method annotated with @ModelAttribute which returns a `new CategoryAdd()`